# Statistic test for samples with different sizes

Tags: hypothesis-testing

What statistical test should i use for comparing samples with different sizes?

I am using a public dataset from DataSUS, I want to see if there are differences between the mean/median for the same type of surgery in different hospitals.
The number of surgeries is distributed along the years:

For surgery type 1, hospital x has a sample size of 653 from 2011 to 2021 and hospital y has a sample size of 4502 in the same period (I have the numbers for each year too)

Then what test should i use, considering that i want to test for 4 other types of surgeries for the same period and hospitals?

Comment: Given that this is time series data, this might get complicated. If, for ex., the number of surgeries were to increase over time, testing the overall mean might not make much sense, especially if you have uneven sample sizes. Could you append some plots of your data to the question?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is it that you want to test, and what is that muddies the testing about sample sizes? The sample sizes look equal in the posted table. // The time series nature of this data could complicate matters.